# Fazer update com parâmetros de uma view

Tags: view

Bom dia.
Criei uma `view` para pegar dados concatenados de várias colunas.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `canal` AS
    SELECT 
        `a`.`id_campaign` AS `id_campaign`,
        `a`.`state` AS `state`,
        CONCAT('id_dialing_list_number_',
                `b`.`id_dialing_list`) AS `Num_Lista`
    FROM
        (`campaign` `a`
        JOIN `campaign_dialing_list` `b` ON (`a`.`id_campaign` = `b`.`id_campaign`))
    WHERE
        `a`.`state` = '3'
```

E me retorna esses dados:

```
d_campaign,state,Num_Lista
100,3,id_dialing_list_number_74
100,3,id_dialing_list_number_186
209,3,id_dialing_list_number_185
209,3,id_dialing_list_number_115
211,3,id_dialing_list_number_237
213,3,id_dialing_list_number_68
210,3,id_dialing_list_number_89
214,3,id_dialing_list_number_354
212,3,id_dialing_list_number_156
217,3,id_dialing_list_number_163
```

Gostaria de pegar da coluna `Num_lista` e fazer um update nessas respectivas tabelas.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?.

Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma opção de solução:

Uma forma de fazer o que você precisa é usando a seguinte execução:

```
INSERT INTO nome_da_tabela (nome_da_coluna)
SELECT nome_do_campo_da_view FROM nome_da_view;
```

Desta forma você irá, como visto na primeira linha, inserir nas referidas coluna e tabela, o conteúdo obtido da View.

Neste caso, é importante tomar cuidado com as chaves primárias, para não inseri-las novamente na mesma tabela e com os tipos dos dados, para não inserir por exemplo, um campo varchar da View em um campo integer da tabela.

Grande abraço.